# UWP app DropDownButton cannot be added to IGridList

Tags: xaml, xamarin, uwp

I am trying to create a Flyout menu for each grid cell that opens via dropdown button. However, whatever I try, I cannot get it to work or even build I should say.

My code is

```
<DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="1" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="2" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Text="3" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                                <controls:DropDownButton Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="End"></controls:DropDownButton>
```

but I get the error
`XLS0503    A value of type 'DropDownButton' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'IGridList1'`

Is there some parent element I need to add before?

Comment: Is it a Xamarin forms app? There are `ViewCell` or `Label ` controls in UWP

Comment: Yes, Xamarin, should have noted it. I have used them both, but I would like to enhance the row even more

Comment: I can't find a control named DropDownButton in the xamarin, it seems a uwp native control.

Comment: The child view in the Grid must be inherited from the Xamarin.Forms.View.

Comment: Yes, DropDownButton seems to be a UWP native control, so how could I achieve the same thing with Xamarin? And about the View element - it says "The type 'View' does not support direct content" When i try to put something as a sub-element of View

Comment: There is no a such control in the xamarin. You may need to find a UI library which has a such view.

Comment: Im unfortunately bound to Xamarin. Another option I explored is tooltip upon clicking of button, but that didn't work either, tooltip didn't show up, although debug set it visible. I was using sample from here https://github.com/CrossGeeks/TooltipSample

Answer (score 0):

UWP application doesn't have *ViewCell* element.
Look for all available GUI and Layout elements in [WinUI3](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9P3JFPWWDZRC) or [WinUI2](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MSVH128X2ZT)

Read more about WinUI2 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/)

Comment: Do you mean _ViewCell_?

Comment: Yes, _ViewCell_. My mistake.